# 'Latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 1011-1013: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am newbie in Python so my method to make the code work is by referring to other people's code and modify until it solves my problem.

I have tried to make a code to download the 'pdf' attachment from the email with particular name. I have made the code and it worked well in my windows laptop. But the problem is my laptop cannot run 24 hours so I was planning to move the code to Raspberry Pi 4 device.

I had to make some adjustments on the code to make it works in the Raspberry Pi, and eventually worked for sometimes. But then now, when I tried to run the code from the terminal in Raspberry Pi, it always shows an error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 1011-1013: ordinal not in range(256)

What is going on here? Why does the exact same code work last week, but doesn't work today?

Below is my code:

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import os
import sys
import webbrowser

org_email = "@yahoo.com"
username = "test123" + org_email
password = "xxxxxxx"
smtp_server = "imap.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 993

def create(text): #clean text for creating a folder
    if "CCI Daily" in text:
        foldername = "CCI Daily"
    elif "ICT" in text:
        foldername = "Platts ICT"
    elif "Argus Coal Daily International" in text:
        foldername = "Argus"
    elif "Fenwei Index Price Comparion" in text:
        foldername = "Fenwei Index Price Comparisons"
    else:
        foldername = "Spam"
    return foldername

#Create Connection
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(smtp_server)
mail.login(username,password)

#Which Gmail Folder to Select
mail.select("inbox")

type, data = mail.search(None,"ALL")
mail_ids = data[0]
id_list = mail_ids.split()

first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
last_email_id = int(id_list[-1])

print("\nThere are", last_email_id, "emails detected")

for i in range(first_email_id, last_email_id+1):
    a = last_email_id + 1 - i #a = latest email index
    print("\n%s th email:" %a)
    res, msg = mail.fetch(str(a), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance (response, tuple): #parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])

            #decode the email subject
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            if isinstance (subject, bytes):
                subject = subject.decode(encoding)

            #decode the email sender
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            if isinstance (From, bytes):
                From = From.decode(encoding)

            print("Subject: ", subject)
            print("===============================================")
            print("From: ", From)

            #if the email message is multipart
            if msg.is_multipart():
                #iterate over email parts
                for part in msg.walk():
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                    print(content_type)
                    if content_disposition != "None":
                        print(content_disposition)
                
                    try:
                    #get the email body and print the email body
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    except:
                        pass

                    if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                        #print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                        print(body)
                    elif "attachment" in content_disposition:
                        #download attachment
                        filename = part.get_filename()
                        if "ICT" in filename or "CCI" in filename:
                            folder_name = create(filename) #create specific folder for specific filename
                            print("Foldername:", folder_name)
                            if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                                #make a folder for this email
                                os.mkdir(folder_name)
                            filepath = os.path.join(folder_name,filename)
                            open(filepath, "wb").write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                            exit()
                        else:
                            print("We do not download this attachment")
```

Comment: Exactly which characters can't it encode? Is it `u'\u201c'`, for example?
And does it tell you which line of the file caused the error? (messages in "Traceback (most recent call last)")

Comment: What do you get if you just print the payload? `print(part.get_payload(decode=True))`

Comment: It seems really odd that a raspberry pi would default to latin-1.

Comment: @MarkRansom yesterday i clicked 'Recommended Software' in my Raspberry Pi, and it seems did a system update.. i suspect it doesnt work because of the system update

Comment: This lib let you to focus on your work https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 0):

Since you actually have an encoding name, chances are you have malformed messages, that tough they specify the "latin1" encoding, they have characters that it can't handle. Pass the extra named argument errors="replace" in your calls to "decode": out of range chars will be replaced with a "�", but the app won't stop.

Comment: Hi, i read a thread where someone exactly has the same problem as mine. So he only changed the Character Set in Locale to UTF-8 and my code runs again now. Previously the character set might be changed accidentally to ISO-8859-1 and it was the root cause.. Thank you for your help guys, it is now resolved~

Answer (score 0):

If it's Unicode text file, don't use `open(filepath, "wb")`, instead use `open(filepath, "w", encoding="utf-8")`.
You can also use try/except block depending on the situation:

```
try:
   open(filepath, "wb").write(body)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
   open(filepath, "w", encoding="utf-8").write(body)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work as well. So I tried to run this python script in two ways. 
When I run the script through Thonny Python IDE, it just runs normally and does the job well.
But when I run the script through terminal where requires me to type 'python download.py', it will show me the 'latin-1 codec bla bla bla' error

So I am really confused now because last week, my crontab still execute this script normally. How can one script works if executed through IDE, and not work if executed through the terminal. I am still thinking there should be nothing wrong with the code

Comment: @BrianKristianto it's probably something to do with the environment, perhaps the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING`.